# GTM OAuth iOS5 retaining access token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, oauth

I don't want users to go through the authorization step every time they fire up the app. Instead, I want the app to save the access tokens from a 3 legged OAuth 1.0a process and use those to access protected resources.

Here's what I have thus far, and it keeps asking me to authorize (not sign in) every time.

Any ideas? Please help. Using GTMOauth library.

```
    - (void)signIn
{
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice/oauth/request_token/"];
    NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice/oauth/access_token/"];
    NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice/oauth/authorize/"];
    NSString *scope = @"http://webservice";

    auth = [self getAuthForWebservice];

    [auth setCallback:@"http://webservice/OAuthCallback"];    

    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                language:nil
                                                         requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                       authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                          accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                          authentication:auth
                                                          appServiceName:@"webservice"
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                           animated:YES];

    [self navigationController].navigationBarHidden = YES;    
}


- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch)];

    }
}

- (void)doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch {
    NSString *urlStr = @"http://webservice/resource/";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [auth authorizeRequest:request];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gtm-oauth controller saves the token to the keychain. Read it back from the keychain when the app starts again, as shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction#Retrieving_Authorization_from_the_Keychain).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't look in the wiki. Usually I'm good at scouring for documentation...